# How to pass array as argument in TCL from one proc to another proc

Tags: tcl

I am reading some values from a file and reading them as `data(signal1),data(signal2)` in one proc - `read()`. 
From this proc I am calling another proc `usage_12(data(signal1))` and want to send `data(signal1)` as argument and use in `usage_12(args)`

```
proc read() {args} {
    #import data from a file and store {signal1 signal2} data
    usage_12 $data(signal1)
}

proc usage_12 {args} {
   foreach trq $args {
      #iterate for all values
   }
}
```

want to iterate in `usage_12` for all values in `data(signal1)`

data(signal1) example contents:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`args`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm) is a special variable name for `proc`s, you either need to change it, or indicate that you want to iterate on the elements of the first argument only:

```
proc usage_12 {data} {
    foreach trq $data {
        puts $trq     ;# Just printing the value
        #iterate for all values
    }
}
```

Or

```
proc usage_12 {args} {
    foreach trq [lindex $args 0] {
        puts $trq     ;# Just printing the value
        #iterate for all values
    }
}
```

Both of the above will print 1 through 6 on their own line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array get arrayname` and `array set arrayname` for this purpose. It is done in following steps.

- convert array into list using `array get arrayname`
- pass the list as argument
- convert, if you want, list into array using `array set arrayname $list`
  And then you will be able to use *copy of array* in the proc.

```
proc print_array {key_vals} {
        array set data $key_vals
        foreach key [array names data] {
            puts $data($key)
        }
    }
array set data [list 0 sdf 1 sddsf 2 dssd]
print_array [array get data]
```

Note: If you want to use *same array ie not copy of array*, you can use upvar.